# Añadir "_cntr" a la mitad de las columnas de cualquier dataframe dentro de una función

Tags: r, funciones, dataframe, rstudio

Soy nuevo programando en R y he tenido que hacer una función que recoga un dataframe y devuelva ese mismo dataframe con el doble de columnas que el original y en esas columnas nuevas, los valores tienen que ser el valor original menos la media (la media es la fila 51 del dataframe). El caso es que la función la tengo hecha y funciona, lo único que me faltaría hacer es renombrar de la columna 9:16 del dataframe, tienen que tener el mismo nombre que las columnas originales y se les añade "_cntr"

Había pensado añadir el _cntr con la función paste, pero no me funciona o no la estoy utilizando bien, tenía pensado algo así:

```
nom = paste("cntr",sep = '_')
colnames(state.df3) = nom
```

y esto meterlo dentro de la función que compartiré a continuación, pero esto me cambia el nombre de la primera columna por centr y me deja el resto de columnas con el valor NA.

Si hago lo siguiente:

```
nom = paste("cntr",9:16,sep = '_')
colnames(state.df3) = nom
```

Nos devuelve cntr1, cntr2, cntr3... y no quiero que me devuelva eso, quiero que me devuelva "Population_cntr", "Income_cntr", "Illiteracy_cntr"... todo eso a partir de la columna 9 hasta la 16 (ya que es donde empiezan los duplicados)

Al dataframe que estoy utilizando como prueba se puede acceder aquí:

```
state.df = as.data.frame(state.x77)
```

Y esta es la función que tengo hecha hasta ahora, solo me faltaría modificar los nombre de las columnas 9:16.

```
mi_funcion <- function(df) { 
  row_medias <- tail(df, 1)
  row_resto <- head(df, -1)
  tmp <- rbind(row_resto - as.list(row_medias), row_medias)
  resultado = cbind(df, tmp)
  return(resultado)
}
```

Si alguien me pudiese echar una mano y decirme en que estoy fallando estaría muy agradecido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edita los nombres del las columnas y `paste` "_cntr" asignando a `colnames`

`colnames(df)[9:16] <- paste(colnames(df)[9:16],"cntr", sep="_")`

Answer (score 1):

Para cambiar los nombres desde un rango de columnas puedes hacer:

```
names(resultado)[9:16] = paste0(names(resultado)[9:16],"_cntr")
```

de manera automatizada, es decir, desde la mitad +1 de un df hasta el final, esto se traduce a:

```
names(resultado)[(length(resultado)/2+1):length(resultado)] = # nombres desde la mitad del df al final
  paste0(names(resultado)[(length(resultado)/2+1):length(resultado)],"_cntr")
```

Agregando eso antes del final de tu función debería funcionar